Repeated Measures ANOVA/Linear Mixed Effects Model and Missing Data
I'm conducting a study measuring happiness across 4 time points, aiming to determine if there's an increase in overall happiness. The required sample size is 24 for four time points and 28 for three. However, I need help with participant retention. Here's the breakdown:
Survey 1: 24 participants
Survey 2: 36 participants (8 returned from Survey 1)
Survey 3: 60 participants (24 returned from Survey 2, none from Survey 1)
Survey 4: 100 participants (some overlap with previous surveys)
To analyze the data, I'm considering only those who completed at least two surveys from Surveys 2, 3, or 4. This resulted in 36 participants and about 20% missing data. I've excluded Survey 1 participants due to more than 50% missing data.
My questions are:
Is it statistically valid to include only participants who completed at least two surveys from Surveys 2-4?
Should I impute missing data and use repeated measures ANOVA, or would a linear mixed-effects model better handle the missing data?
My model is straightforward:
Happiness score - dependent variable, Time - independent variable.
Any advice would be greatly appreciated! I appreciate any help you can provide.

There is no definitive answer here. Can you tell us more about the predictors you want to include in your model? Do you have missing data on them? If they are time-varying, then presumably, yes. If they are person-level, time-invariant, then presumably no.

@ErikRuzek Our study aims to assess whether there has been an increase in overall happiness among participants who used our interventions—such as dance classes, art classes, meditation, and other resources—available prior to the study's start. Once these tools were accessible, we began conducting quarterly surveys with volunteers to track any improvements in their happiness over time.

@ErikRuzek Our initial plan was to use repeated measures ANOVA, but we've encountered issues with participant retention across time points. For example, some participants joined only in later surveys, some appeared in the first and then skipped others, while others returned sporadically. This inconsistency led me to consider alternative approaches, particularly linear mixed models (LMM), which handle missing data more flexibly.

@ErikRuzek For participants who completed at least two surveys across all four time points, we found:
21 participants in Time 1, 34 in Time 2, 45 in Time 3, and 47 in Time 4, resulting in 37% missing data.
For those who completed at least two surveys across three time points (Time 2, 3, and 4), we found:
32 participants in Time 2, 43 in Time 3, and 44 in Time 4, resulting in 22% missing data.

@ErikRuzek I also reviewed generalized estimating equations (GEE), which offer population-averaged estimates suitable for analyzing general trends across the sample rather than individual trajectories. GEE appears robust with missing data, but I’m unfamiliar with its assumptions on correlation structures, like "exchangeable" or "autoregressive."
I'm unsure of the best approach, as I initially thought LMM might be a simple alternative to repeated measures ANOVA. If you have any recommendations, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
Thank you very much.

Thanks for the context, @anna eyre. Just a few ideas for you to consider:

A linear mixed effect model (with a continuous outcome) provides population estimates. These come from the fixed effects (the non-random coefficients). So even though you are specifying individual trajectories in your model, you still get population estimates. If your outcome was 0/1 (or of a categorical nature), then you need to do some additional work to get population estimates from generalized linear mixed models. See this thread.
In terms of missing data, I assume your model is what you indicated above. In lme4, it would be something like the following: m1 <- lmer(out ~ time + (time|id), data). If that is the case, the model will use all available information in estimating the time trend of the outcome. So if an individual only contributed two time points, both of their data points would be used.
A question for you to consider is how to code time. You have some participants who did 4 classes, some who did 3, 2, and so on. In the case of 4 classes, then you can code time 1 as 0 (making 0 meaningful such that the the intercept is the mean outcome value at the first occasion), 2 as 1, 3 as 2, and 4 as 3. But what about for those with 3 time points? What if they started at study timepoint 2? I would probably still code their first time point as 0 because that is when they started the intervention. Similarly for those with 2 or even 1 observation.


My outcome is continuous. My data is MAR so I think LMM is a good choice here. At first I considered using model as follows: m1 <- lmer(out ~ time + (1|id), data) but thanks to your suggestion I now believe that m1 <- lmer(out ~ time + (time|id), data) make more sense. Since participants attended at varying time points (some with gaps in participation), their happiness trajectories may differ. What I understand is that, for instance, one participant might have a steady increase in happiness, while another may have no change or even a decrease.

The random slope (time|id) accounts for individual variation in how happiness changes over time. Without it, I would assume the effect of time is the same for everyone, which might not reflect my data. The random intercept (1|id) accounts for differences in baseline happiness scores among individuals.
The random slope (time|id) allows the model to capture individual-specific trajectories. I think I'll compare these two models and see which one fits better.

this is the first time I have considered time coding. I was planning to use time as a continuous variable. I felt like it was essential to leave the time as is because times 2 and 4 are farther apart; therefore, the estimates for the missing values should use that information. But after your suggestion, I might have to account for that.

So if I understand it correctly - let’s consider a participant who completes Time 2, Time 3, and Time 4:
Time 2 would be coded as 0 (first measurement for this participant)
Time 3 would be coded as 1
Time 4 would be coded as 2
For a participant who attends Time 1 and Time 4:
Time 1 would be coded as 0
Time 4 would be coded as 1
This coding probably helps ensure that my analysis properly handles the different number of observations per participant, while still allowing for comparisons across time. But I'm still unsure if this is the way.

What if I have a participant who attended 1st, 3rd and 4th survey? Should I code the time as 0,1,2?

Or should I code it as 0, 2, 3 to account for that difference? Lastly, could I get by without spending any time coding?

@annaeyre - you can code time so that the timepoints actually represent the amount of time that elapsed between observations (that's ideal). So if the entire period of data collection was 12 months, time 1 could be month 0, and then time 2 is however many months (or days) later that occurred, and similarly for times 3 and 4. If people were measured on different days around the expected date for a given time period, you could code their time variables appropriately to reflect that.  Re your last comment, I would code as 0, 2, 3 if you keep the 0-3 coding.

Thanks. I'll look into different coding options. I want to compare different versions of the model. m1 <- lmer(out ~ time + (1|id), data), m2 <- lmer(out ~ time + (time|id), data), and also comparing the model with time either being continuos vs categorical. m3 <- lmer(out ~ factor(time) + (1|id), data). Do you think that the time should be looked at only one of the two options? I'll use the likelihood ratio test to compare the models using the anova() function.
